# Как сделать несколько экземпляров класса на страницу?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы на одной странице можно было использовать несколько инстансов класса `Slider`
 и они не конфликтовали друг с другом

```js
class Slider {
  constructor(count, page, pageActive, pagerItem, pagerItemActive, timer) {
    this.count = count;
    this.page = page;
    this.pageActive = pageActive;
    this.pagerItem = pagerItem;
    this.pagerItemActive = pagerItemActive;
    this.timer = timer;
  }

  slide(index = this.count) {
    if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);

    const nextIndex = index % this.count;

    this.pagerItem.forEach(el => el.classList.remove(this.pagerItemActive));
    this.page.forEach(el => el.classList.remove(this.pageActive));

    this.pagerItem[nextIndex].classList.add(this.pagerItemActive);
    this.page[nextIndex].classList.add(this.pageActive);

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.slide(index + 1);
    }, 6000);
  }

  nextSlide() {
    let index = this.page.findIndex(el => el.className.includes(this.pageActive));
    index = index + 1 === this.count ? -1 : index;
    this.slide(++index);
  }

  prevSlide() {
    let index = this.page.findIndex(el => el.className.includes(this.pageActive));
    index = index <= 0 ? this.count : index;
    this.slide(--index);
  }
}

const slider__page = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider__page')];
const page_active = 'slider__page_active';
const slider__pagerItem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider__pager-item')];
const pagerItem = '.on-page__pager-item';
const pagerItem_active = 'on-page__pager-item_active';
const slider__btnPrev = '.slider__btn-prev';
const slider__btnNext = '.slider__btn-next';

const sliderNew = new Slider($(slider__pagerItem).length, slider__page, page_active, slider__pagerItem, pagerItem_active);

sliderNew.slide();

$(pagerItem).on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass(sliderNew.pagerItemActive)) {
    $(this).addClass(pagerItem_active);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass(pagerItem_active);
  }
});

$(slider__pagerItem).on('click', function() {
  sliderNew.slide($(this).index());
});

$(slider__btnPrev).on('click', () => {
  sliderNew.prevSlide();
});

$(slider__btnNext).on('click', () => {
  sliderNew.nextSlide();
});
```

```css
.on-page__pager {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slider__btn-prev,
.slider__btn-next {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.on-page__pager-item {
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.on-page__pager-item_active {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid #131111;
}

.slider__page {
  display: none;
}

.slider__page_active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="on-page__pager slider__pager">
    <div class="slider__btn-prev">PREV</div>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">01</span>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">02</span>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">03</span>
    <div class="slider__btn-next">NEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="on-page__slider__page slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/400/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать для каждого слайдера уникальный `id` и по нему определять все необходимые компоненты слайдера.

```js
class Slider {
  constructor(sliderElement) {
    this._element = sliderElement;

    this.page = sliderElement.find('.slider__page').get();
    this.pageActive = 'slider__page_active';
    this.pagerItem = sliderElement.find('.slider__pager-item').get();
    this.pagerItemActive = 'on-page__pager-item_active';
    this.count = sliderElement.find('.on-page__pager-item').length;

    this.btnPrev = sliderElement.find('.slider__btn-prev');
    this.btnNext = sliderElement.find('.slider__btn-next');

    this.timer = 0;
    
    this._init();
  }

  slide(index = this.count) {
    if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);

    const nextIndex = index % this.count;

    this.pagerItem.forEach(el => el.classList.remove(this.pagerItemActive));
    this.page.forEach(el => el.classList.remove(this.pageActive));

    this.pagerItem[nextIndex].classList.add(this.pagerItemActive);
    this.page[nextIndex].classList.add(this.pageActive);

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.slide(index + 1);
    }, 6000);
  }
  
   _init() {
    const self = this;
    this._element.find('.slider__pager-item').on('click', function() {
      self.slide($(this).index("span"));
    });

    $(this.btnPrev).on('click', () => {
      this.prevSlide();
    });

    $(this.btnNext).on('click', () => {
      this.nextSlide();
    });
    
    this.slide();
  }

  nextSlide() {
    let index = this.page.findIndex(el => el.className.includes(this.pageActive));
    index = index + 1 === this.count ? -1 : index;
    this.slide(++index);
  }

  prevSlide() {
    let index = this.page.findIndex(el => el.className.includes(this.pageActive));
    index = index <= 0 ? this.count : index;
    this.slide(--index);
  }
}

const slider2 = new Slider($('#slider--1'));
const slider1 = new Slider($('#slider--2'));
```

```css
.on-page__pager {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slider__btn-prev,
.slider__btn-next {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.on-page__pager-item {
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.on-page__pager-item_active {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid #131111;
}

.slider__page {
  display: none;
}

.slider__page_active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider" id="slider--1">
  <div class="on-page__pager slider__pager">
    <div class="slider__btn-prev">PREV</div>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">01</span>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">02</span>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">03</span>
    <div class="slider__btn-next">NEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="on-page__slider__page slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/340/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/340/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/340/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider" id="slider--2">
  <div class="on-page__pager slider__pager">
    <div class="slider__btn-prev">PREV</div>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">01</span>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">02</span>
    <span class="on-page__pager-item slider__pager-item">03</span>
    <div class="slider__btn-next">NEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="on-page__slider__page slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/247/340/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1010/340/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__page">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/340/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```